# Cloud Dataproc can't access Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a cloud dataproc Spark job that also uses Cloud Strage API from Drvier side (to choose specific files from the same folder to work with).

Here are maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.101.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the simplest version of the code that fails:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage._

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
--> storage.list("intent_raw")
  }
}
```

here is stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:84)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.listBlobs(StorageImpl.java:372)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:328)
--> at ai.mandal.cloud.dataproc.Test$.main(Test.scala:14)
    at ai.mandal.cloud.dataproc.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My question is generally what can cause it, and also if I am running it from a dataproc service (which has access to the bucket), do I need to configure separate credentials for that.

Comment: I've also added the latest guava dependency, didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add

```
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst = true
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst = true
```

to job properties.

The problem is caused by conflicting versions of guava found in `google-cloud-storage` and the host environment.

Google recommends to shade the conflicting guava in your dependency, I've tried that too but that didn't work for this case.